# SharePoint 2013 Webparts

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

we have had a sharepoint site designed for us, attached is a picture of the webpart. [image: webpart]

we are wanting the line of text to be smaller "work summary" less words in a other way.
but I cant work out how to change this.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This impossible to answer here. Nobody knows the structure of the custom site and/or the functionality of this web part. You may want to go back to the developer.

If this were an out of the box list I would guess that

- the list has a multi-line column called "Work Summary"
- the screenshot shows an XSLT list view web part where that column has is linked to the item (hence the blue and underline), or a DVWP where the column has been formatted as a link so something.

In this case it would be possible to create a DVWP that uses XSLT to show only the first x characters or x words of the Work Summary.

In a multi-line text field you'd first have to strip out the HTML tags and then grab the text. Marc Anderson has a blog post with the details of the XSLT here:

[Displaying the First N Words of a Long Rich Text Column with XSL](http://sympmarc.com/2009/01/20/displaying-the-first-n-words-of-a-long-text-column-with-xsl/)